# Unhandled Promise Rejection: Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to print a simple pdf document form my app using printAsync. I found a code that works and I tried using the same method in my app but this error came out. I am not sure of what is triggering the error.

Here's my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';
import * as Print from 'expo-print';
import {TouchableOpacity, TextInput} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  state ={
    assetsLoaded: false,
    idNumber: 12345,
  };

 printPdf () {
  Print.printAsync({
    html:
  <html>
    <body style = {styles.container}>
      <div style= "height: 100%; width: 100%, margin: 20px" />
      <h1 style={{fontFamily: 'code39', fontSize: 100 }}>{this.state.idNumber}</h1>
      <h2>{this.state.idNumber}</h2>
    </body>
  </html>
  })
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      'code39': require('./assets/Font/Code39r.ttf'),
    });

    this.setState({assetsLoaded: true})
  }  

  render() {
    const {assetsLoaded} = this.state;

    if (assetsLoaded) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={{fontFamily: 'code39', fontSize: 100 }}>{this.state.idNumber}</Text>
          <Text> </Text>
          <Text>{this.state.idNumber}</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity 
            style = {styles.button}  
            onPress ={ ()=> this.printPdf()}>
            <Text style ={styles.buttonText}>PRINT PDF</Text>    
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
      }
    else {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>Font load Fail</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
    }

  }


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: 10,

  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#7a42f4',
    padding: 10,
    margin: 15,
    height: 40,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
  },
});
```

The error is this:
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Exception in HostFunction: Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aa4Zb.png)

Comment: try to remove font path  and do run if its work then you have to provide correct path of font...